# How to set colors in react carbon design chart

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, carbon-design-system

I'm using the react library of [carbon design charts](https://github.com/carbon-design-system/carbon-charts) and I'm having difficulties setting custom colors using `getFillColor` function in the chart options properties :

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { DonutChart } from "@carbon/charts-react";
import "@carbon/charts/styles.css";

const colors = {
  java: "#FF0000",
  javascript: "#00FF00",
  "c++": "#0000FF"
};

const chartData = [
  {
    group: "java",
    value: 300
  },
  {
    group: "javascript",
    value: 600
  },
  {
    group: "c++",
    value: 200
  }
];

const demoDonutOptions = {
  getFillColor: (field) => {
    return colors[field];
  },
  height: "300px"
};

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h3>React Donut chart with label</h3>
      <div>
        <DonutChart data={chartData} options={demoDonutOptions} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

The code above works in v0.40.2 and below, checkout [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/carbon-react-donut-color-0402-0u03z?file=/src/index.js), it correctly set the colors :

[image]

but in v0.40.3 and above, it doesn't work anymore, see [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/carbon-react-donut-color-04013-1lq2v?file=/src/index.js), the colors remain unchanged :

[image]

What is the correct way of setting colors in carbon design chart framework ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found out that [from the history](https://github.com/carbon-design-system/carbon-charts/commit/8e32712652a4726da5a978313e01c1139d8baf77), there was a change that needs the `color.scale` property to be specified in the chart options:

```
const demoDonutOptions = {
  color: {
    scale: {
      java: "#FF0000",
      javascript: "#00FF00",
      "c++": "#0000FF"
    }
  },
  height: "300px"
};
```

Note that all the groups need to be specified in `color.scale` for this example to be working :

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { DonutChart } from "@carbon/charts-react";
import "@carbon/charts/styles.css";

const colors = {
  java: "#FF0000",
  javascript: "#00FF00",
  "c++": "#0000FF"
};

const chartData = [
  {
    group: "java",
    value: 300
  },
  {
    group: "javascript",
    value: 600
  },
  {
    group: "c++",
    value: 200
  }
];

const demoDonutOptions = {
  color: {
    scale: colors
  },
  height: "300px"
};

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h3>React Donut chart with label</h3>
      <div>
        <DonutChart data={chartData} options={demoDonutOptions} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

[Checkout this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/carbon-react-donut-color-04013-working-p30ol?file=/src/index.js:0-774)

It's also possible to use `getFillColors` which overrides the `color.scale` but it seems the `color.scale` is compulsory at this time